# overriding login.phtml is not working

Tags: magento2

I have added an input hidden field inside the form tag of login.phtml file in magneto.

`<input name="login[pageurl]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prevpageurl; ?>" />`

whenever echo is used inside the tag whole file is disappeared from the frontend. if I remove echo $prevpageurl login form is showing.

I am not able to find out why this error is happening. please help me to resolve this

Comment: please provide file path location

Comment: its in custom_theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form

Comment: please check third party plugin where it is already override.

Comment: $prevpageurl first check its value then use it